# Convertir de Hex String a Unsigned Char Array en C++

Tags: c++

Necesito convertir una cadena de caracteres string a unsigned char array de este modo:

```
string hex_str_texto = "0A4F1B3D5EEF354A";
unsigned char uchar_texto[80];
```

Salida:

```
uchar_texto[0] = 0x0A //Primeros dos elementos del string 
uchar_texto[1] = 0x4F
uchar_texto[2] = 0x1B
```

Esto sirve bien algunas veces pero algunas veces no funciona (desconozco el motivo):

```
char *c_key1 = new char[80 + 1];

for(unsigned i = 0, unsigned_char_val; i < hex_str_texto.length(); i += 2)
{
    sscanf(hex_str_texto.c_str() + i, "%2X", &unsigned_char_val);
    c_key1[i/2] = unsigned_char_val;
    uchar_texto[i/2] = c_key1[i/2];
}

delete c_key1;
```

Intenté esta otra forma pero no funciona (el arreglo siempre es cero):

```
sscanf(hex_str_texto.c_str(), "%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX...",
        &uchar_texto[0], &uchar_texto[1], &uchar_texto[2]...);
```

¿Hay otra forma de resolver esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si puedes compilar en C++17, puedes sacar provecho de la función [`std::from_chars` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars):

```
/* Pasado a formacion de char por comodidad para su proceso
   podrías usar string::data en su lugar. */
const char hex_str_texto[]{"FABADACAFEDEADF00D"};

int main()
{
    /* Al añadir las llaves {} al final, todos los elementos
       se inicializan a 0 */
    unsigned char uchar_texto[80]{};

    for (int b = 0, e = sizeof(hex_str_texto) - 1; b != e; b += 2)
    {
        std::from_chars(hex_str_texto + b, hex_str_texto + b + 2, uchar_texto[b / 2], 16);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si tu compilador no da soporte a C++17, puedes usar un [`std::stringstream` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
const std::string hex_str_texto{"FABADACAFEDEADF00D"};

int main()
{
    /* Al añadir las llaves {} al final, todos los elementos
       se inicializan a 0 */
    unsigned char uchar_texto[80]{};

    for (int b = 0, e = hex_str_texto.length(); b != e; b += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << hex_str_texto.substr(b, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        uchar_texto[b / 2] = valor;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y si no puedo compilar en C++17?

Comment: Si no puedes compilar en C++17, puedes usar un [`std::stringstream`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/196159/2742) o la solución de Trauma

Answer (score 5):

Una posible solución, usando C++ *puro*:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static char fromASCII( const char c ) {
  return ( c < 'A' ) ? ( c - 48 ) : ( c - 55 );
}

int main( ) {
  std::string hex( "0A4F1B3D5EEF354A" );
  std::vector< unsigned char > result;

  const char *ptr = hex.c_str( );

  while( *ptr ) {
    char sub = fromASCII( *ptr ) * 15;
    ++ptr;
    sub += fromASCII( *ptr );

    ++ptr;

    result.push_back( sub );
  }

  for( auto idx : result ) std::cout << (int)idx << ' ';

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Como ves, la conversión de un par de *bytes* a un solo valor hexadecimal es bastante sencilla:

```
resultado = ( par[0] * 15 ) + par[1];
```

Usamos una función auxiliar para obtener el valor *crudo* de cada carácter ASCII; si es >= `'A'`, el valor numérico es `char - 55`, y `char - 48` en otro caso.

Ten en cuenta que no comprobamos errores; por ejemplo, si usas letras minúsculas, el resultado será *curioso* ;-)

Dejo a tu disfrute el soportar minúsculas; solo hay que modificar levemente la función `fromASCII( )`.

Comment: C++ puro, pero del año 98 ;P

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Algunos seguimos *anclados en el pasado*, que le vamos a hacer :-)